# How can I avoid this Stale Element Reference error using Selenium with Python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have been attempting to use Selenium to complete a webscrape of product information, and have managed to successfully scrape the information I need from three or four category pages at a time (up to 120 products in total). My goal is to scrape c.4000 products from c.100 category pages.

However, I have been receiving "stale element reference" errors sporadically, which stop the scrape from completing. The more products I try to collect, the more likely it seems that the error will occur and the whole scrape fail.

I have attempted to avoid the error by re-adding the webdriver to "refresh" the "hrefs" element which seems to be causing the problem, but this doesn't seem to have helped.

This approach seemed to fix the error when it was triggered by the individual product elements. I changed my code to write web elements directly into a dictionary, rather than assigning them to a variable and then writing them to a dictionary (See lower down my code for example of the previous approach commented out), and this seems to have worked.

The problem now seems to be focussed on line72: href_list.append(href.get_attribute('href'))

This is the error I repeatedly receive:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:\Python\aldi\aldi\selenium_test5.py", line 79, in <module>
    href_scraper(all_urls)
  File "h:\Python\aldi\aldi\selenium_test5.py", line 72, in href_scraper
    href_list.append(href.get_attribute('href'))
  File "H:\Python\aldi\aldi_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webelement.py", line 172, in get_attribute
    attribute_value = self.parent.execute_script(
  File "H:\Python\aldi\aldi_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 491, in execute_script
    return self.execute(command, {
  File "H:\Python\aldi\aldi_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 428, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "H:\Python\aldi\aldi_venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 243, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.StaleElementReferenceException: Message: stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document
```

The csv file 'url_list.csv' contains the following lines:

```
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/specially-selected
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/vegan-range
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/bakery
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/fresh-food
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/drinks
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/food-cupboard
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/frozen
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/chilled-food
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/baby-toddler
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/health-beauty
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/household
https://groceries.aldi.co.uk/en-GB/pet-care
```

And here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from fp.fp import FreeProxy
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
import csv

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')

proxy = FreeProxy(rand=True, country_id=['GB'], elite=True).get()

with open('url_list.csv') as f:
    base_urls = [line.strip() for line in f]

# Collect category page links from main site

cat_urls = []
def cat_url_collector(base_urls):
    for base_url in base_urls:
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(base_url)
        time.sleep(1.5)
        driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        extra_cat_urls = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'dropdown-item')
              
        def cat_href_lister(extra_cat_urls, cat_urls):
            for extra_url in extra_cat_urls:
                text_url = extra_url.get_attribute('href')
                if '?sortDirection=asc&page=' not in text_url:
                    pass
                else:
                    cat_urls.append(text_url)
            return cat_urls
        cat_href_lister(extra_cat_urls, cat_urls)
    
    return cat_urls

cat_url_collector(base_urls)
 
# Combine base urls & extra pages, then de-dupe

all_urls = base_urls + cat_urls
all_urls = list(set(all_urls))

# Collect product page links from category pages

href_list=[]
def href_scraper(all_urls):
    for cat_url in all_urls:
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(cat_url)
        time.sleep(1.5)
        driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)
        
        hrefs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'p.text-default-font')

        for href in hrefs:
            hrefs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'p.text-default-font')
            href_list.append(href.get_attribute('href'))
        
    return href_list

href_scraper(all_urls)

# Collect product information from product page links

prod_info = []
def prod_scraper(href_list):
    prod_count = 0
    for href in href_list:
        options.add_argument('--proxy-server=%s' % proxy)
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        driver.get(href)
        driver.maximize_window()
        time.sleep(1.5)
        driver.find_element('xpath','//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
        time.sleep(2)

        # prod_id = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.sku.small').text[prod_id.text.rindex(' ')+1:]
        prod_name = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'my-0')
        # prod_size = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.text-black-50.font-weight-bold')
        # prod_price = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-price.h4.m-0.font-weight-bold')
        if driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-price.h4.m-0.font-weight-bold') == None:
            with open('rescrape_list.csv') as f:
                rescrape_writer = csv.writer(f)
                rescrape_writer.writerow(href)
        else:

            try:
                prod_prev_price = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[4]/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/del').text
            except:
                prod_prev_price = ""
            
            prod = {
            "URL": href,
            "ID": driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.sku.small').text,
            "Description": driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'my-0').text,
            "Size": driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.text-black-50.font-weight-bold').text,
            "Price": driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'product-price.h4.m-0.font-weight-bold').text.strip('Â£'),
            "Previous Price": prod_prev_price.strip('Â£'),
            "Scrape Date": datetime.now().strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            }
            prod_info.append(prod)
            
            # report progress of scrape (number of products and latest product name)        
            prod_count +=1
            print(str(prod_count) +') '+prod_name.text)
    
    return prod_info

prod_scraper(href_list)

# use pandas to write csv

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(prod_info, orient='columns')
df.to_csv("scrape_data_{}.csv".format(pd.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")))
```

I'd be very grateful for any advice you can provide, as I can't understand how to implement a fix for the "stale element reference" within the for loops in my code.

Thank you.

Comment: this suggests that the DOM is updating when you run find_elements()... when you iterate and use a method on one of the elements, stale element exception will be thrown to tell you that the DOM has updated between the time you found it and used it.  Short answer is to increase your sleep() before running find_elements().   You can also functionize the call (find_elements() and iteration) and re-call if stale element caught.  Also remember that you are getting an array of webelements and these contain a reference to the object in the DOM... not the actual object (until method used)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried running it with a 10 second delay before calling find_elements on the hrefs, but still received the error. Does it seem possible that the DOM is still updating after that long?

Comment: I didn't notice it before, but you are also messing with the iterator there by calling find_elements again while in the loop: hrefs = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'p.text-default-font')   Is there twice... once before the loop and once inside it.  Don't do that.  Also you don't need this sleep:  time.sleep(1.5)  That's right after a .get() call and Selenium will already wait until the page is loaded after a get().

Comment: Thanks, I added it within the iterator in the hope that it would somehow refresh the elements and avoid the error. I removed it when rerunning with a 10 sec delay. I’ll try without the 1.5sec delay before, but I’m still at a bit of a loss why I’m still getting the error with a 10sec delay.

Comment: Not sure, but could be caused by messing with the iterator I guess...  no telling what that'll do to the element references...  I wouldn't think it would cause a stale element exception, but could cause an infinite loop or other weirdness.